# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' - tuples

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, tuples

it throws me an AttributeError when i add .text to the end of the variables in the loop. i remove them and it prints out all the tags along with the info.  i'm not sure why it keeps throwing the AttributeError.

Any help is appreciated T.T

i've tried:

```
biz_name = result.find('span', attrs={'itemprop':'name'}).text
```

and

```
biz_name = result.find('span', attrs={'itemprop':'name'}).text[1:-1]
```

Here is one cell of the results:

```
<span itemprop="name">Efrain Jimenez Jr. General Contractor Inc.</span>
```

and the script:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import csv

r = requests.get('https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=remodeling&geo_location_terms=New+York%2C+NY')

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

results = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'info'})

records = []

for result in results:
    biz_name = result.find('span', attrs={'itemprop':'name'})
    biz_phone = result.find('div', attrs={'itemprop':'telephone'})
    biz_address = result.find('span', attrs={'itemprop':'streetAddress'})
    biz_city = result.find('span', attrs={'itemprop':'addressLocality'})
    biz_zip = result.find('span', attrs={'itemprop':'postalCode'})
    records.append((biz_name, biz_phone, biz_address, biz_city, biz_zip))

df = pd.DataFrame(records, columns=['biz_name', 'biz_phone', 'biz_address', 'biz_city', 'biz_zip'])

df.to_csv('Yp_Remodel.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: One of your find calls returns None. You need to handle that.

Comment: it says it's this line: biz_name = result.find('span', attrs={'itemprop':'name'}) but it's printing this info to the csv (it's the example i gave).  So what could be the problem?

Comment: What does `print biz_name` show in this case?

Comment: lol, a big fat "None".  this is confusing.  If it's returning "None" then why is it printing to the csv?  wouldn't it just error out right then and there?! is my line of thinking totally wrong here?

Comment: Your sure you're not seeing NaN in your CSV output?

Comment: Ok, so just checked my CSV output and it all looks good (no NaN). Is there a way i can share the file with you so you can see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not the fanciest answer, but is seems that in some cases, some of the values are 'None', therefore, you will get an error if you try to access its text. Try this, it worked for me.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import csv

r = requests.get('https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=remodeling&geo_location_terms=New+York%2C+NY')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'info'})

records = []

for result in results:
    biz_name = result.find('span', attrs={'itemprop':'name'}).text if result.find('span', attrs={'itemprop':'name'}) is not None else ''
    biz_phone = result.find('div', attrs={'itemprop':'telephone'}).text if result.find('span', attrs={'itemprop':'telephone'}) is not None else ''
    biz_address = result.find('span', attrs={'itemprop':'streetAddress'}).text if result.find('span', attrs={'itemprop':'streetAddress'}) is not None else ''
    biz_city = result.find('span', attrs={'itemprop':'addressLocality'}).text if result.find('span', attrs={'itemprop':'addressLocality'}) is not None else ''
    biz_zip = result.find('span', attrs={'itemprop':'postalCode'}).text if result.find('span', attrs={'itemprop':'postalCode'}) is not None else ''
    records.append((biz_name, biz_phone, biz_address, biz_city, biz_zip))


df = pd.DataFrame(records, columns=['biz_name', 'biz_phone', 'biz_address', 'biz_city', 'biz_zip'])

df.to_csv('Yp_Remodel.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: doesn't matter to me, it works!  i'd given up and set up a macro in excel to remove all the tags once i got the report.  Thanks for finding a solution. :)